# How to use multiple frameworks at the same time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, frameworks, ejs

I'm kinda confused about how node frameworks work. I've been suggested to use Express.js and ejs because of a specific feature I need (importing html). I'm not sure if it has everything I need, because I haven't done much research into what framework works best for me.

I need the feature as soon as possible to get my website back online. Can I use multiple frameworks at the same time? If not, can I use ejs and some other framework together? How easy/hard is it to uninstall a framework if I can't use 2 at the same time?

I know this sounds like I could just google this, but I've tired searching everywhere and all I get is "Top 10 Nodejs Frameworks for 2020" despite doing things like putting quotes around "at the same time".

Edit: just to clear up some things, I do know that ejs and express work together well. **I don't know what framework I want to use, and I need to use ejs now.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963828/using-multiple-javascript-frameworks-in-a-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EJS is designed to work with Express as they are different and complementary things.

Express is a web server framework.  EJS is a template engine and is designed to work with Express.  They work together just fine.

You can install 100 template engines or 5 web server frameworks and then just code with whichever one you want for any given project. Installing a template engine (or any NPM module) just puts some code on your disk.  It sits there dormant until you actually load it into your project with `require()` or `import`.  So, you can install as many NPM modules as you want and then just program with the ones you actually want to use for any given project. "Installing" an NPM module just puts code on the disk.  It doesn't affect your project at all until you actually load and run that code with `require()` or `import`.

Comment: I know that, I was asking more about what would happen if I installed express and ejs, but later on wanted to switch libraries.

Comment: @DavidZhan - Well, then edit your question to actually say that.  That's not what your question says.  What are you actually concerned about?  You can install 100 template engines and then just code with whichever one you want for any given project.  I don't understand what you're actually trying to ask?  Or, what problem you think you have?  Installing a template engine (or any NPM module) just puts some code on your disk.  It sits there dormant until you actually load it into your project with `require()` or `import`.

Comment: I updated it a minute before your comment.

Comment: My whole question was about how this stuff works. "You can install 100 template engines and then just code with whichever one you want for any given project." is basically an answer for my question.

Comment: @DavidZhan - OK, I made one last attempt to incorporate that previous comment into my answer if you think that answers your question.

Comment: Yes that answers my question perfectly. I'm really new to node, just decided to switch from php to node alongside a switch from wamp to ubuntu. I will eventually get to learning node, but before that I wanted to get my server online. I used the php native include and require a lot, and that was the main thing preventing me from getting my server online, so I wanted to get that out of the way before I did anything with node and frameworks. Sorry for the bad questions, it seems that I am bad at googling (see comment on the question) and all my other questions have gotten downvoted :(